# Python for loop to modify DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

How to use for loop to execute the following operation?

```
df_1=pd.concat([df_ab1,df_xy1], axis=1)  
df_2=pd.concat([df_ab2,df_xy2], axis=1)    
df_3=pd.concat([df_ab3,df_xy3], axis=1)   
df_4=pd.concat([df_ab4,df_xy4], axis=1)    
df_5=pd.concat([df_ab5,df_xy5], axis=1)  
df_6=pd.concat([df_ab6,df_xy6], axis=1)    
df_7=pd.concat([df_ab7,df_xy7], axis=1)  
df_8=pd.concat([df_ab8,df_xy8], axis=1)  
df_9=pd.concat([df_ab9,df_xy9], axis=1)
```

I was thinking something like this

```
for i in np.arange(9):  
    df_str(i+1)=pd.concat([df_ab+str(i+1),df_xy+str(i+1)], axis=1)
```

Apparently, something is missing.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not create variable names dynamically (`df_str(i+1)`). There are workarounds to do that, but don't... Instead go for the list structure you already have in mind. Declare the list `df`; initialize it by: `df = []`. then use `df.append(pd...)` to append the `pd` objects. Then you can access list elements by their index (`pd[0]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not recommended below solution but this will solve your problem

```
variables = locals()
for i in np.arange(9):  
    variables["df_{0}".format(i+1)] = pd.concat([variables["df_ab{0}".format(i+1)],variables["df_xy{0}".format(i+1)]], axis=1)
```

Comment: Agreed, a better code structure would be to have a master df with multiindex

Comment: Many thanks! It seems that there is a right square bracket missing.

Comment: @ER1CZZ yes :-) you got it ~

Comment: @RichieV Thanks for the comment. I will try to use a master df.